# Wordpress themes database upgrade migrations

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a custom theme and would like to know how a wp theme manages database updates. I basically want to setup my database when the theme is activated.

Also, I will be releasing versions for my theme. So when the theme is installed and activated I would like all the previous versions of the theme's db migrations to run.

How should I go about this ? Does WP provide a mechanism to manage database upgrades ?

Note: I won't be publishing my theme to the WP theme bank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://clark-technet.com/2010/09/wordpress-theme-developers-tip-theme-update-noticifications

Here information look.  Is necesary file

> update-notice.php

Comment: Thanks. Although I am looking for a db upgrade mechanism as well.